The error "This range already has a worksheet with different title set"
The program works as it should, that is, it fills in the Google Sheets table, but for some reason, when executing this code, the error This range already has a worksheet with different title set is displayed. There are no gaps and no (at first glance) problems. I don't understand why. I would keep it, but I want my code to be error-free, even minor ones.
import pygsheets
from datetime import datetime


class GoogleTable:
    def __init__(self, credence_service_file: str, googlesheet_file_url: str) -> None:
        self.credence_service_file = credence_service_file
        self.googlesheet_file_url = googlesheet_file_url

 
    def _get_googlesheet_by_url(self):
        try:
            client = self._get_googlesheet_client()
            sheets = client.open_by_url(self.googlesheet_file_url)
            return sheets
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка подключения к Google Таблице: {e}")

 
    def _get_or_create_sheet(self, sheet_title: str):
        sheets = self._get_googlesheet_by_url()
        normalized_title = sheet_title.strip()

        try:
            # Проверяем существующие листы
            for sheet in sheets.worksheets():
                if sheet.title.strip().lower() == normalized_title.lower():
                    print(f"Лист найден: {sheet.title}")
                    return sheet

            # Если лист не найден, создаем новый
            worksheet = sheets.add_worksheet(normalized_title)
            print(f"Создан новый лист: {normalized_title}")
            return worksheet
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка при обработке листа: {e}")

 
    def _get_googlesheet_client(self):
        try:
            return pygsheets.authorize(service_file=self.credence_service_file)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка авторизации Google API: {e}")

 
    def find_admin(self, admin_id: str) -> bool:
        worksheet = self._get_or_create_sheet("Админы")
        worksheet.refresh()

        headers = worksheet.get_row(1)
        if "ID" not in headers:
            return False

        col_index = headers.index("ID") + 1
        all_values = worksheet.get_all_values()

        for row in all_values[1:]:
            if len(row) >= col_index and row[col_index - 1] == admin_id:
                return True
        return False

 
    def add_admin(self, admin_id: str, full_name: str, username: str, phone_number: str) -> None:
        try:
            worksheet = self._get_or_create_sheet("Админы")
            if self.find_admin(admin_id):
                print(f"Админ с ID {admin_id} уже существует.")
                return

            current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %d.%m.%Y")
            new_row = [full_name, admin_id, username, phone_number, current_time]
            worksheet.append_table(new_row, start="A1", dimension="ROWS", overwrite=False)
            print(f"Добавлен новый админ: {full_name}.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка добавления админа: {e}")
            raise

I tried to solve the problem through ChatGPT. Of course, he offers options, but still such an error comes out. I searched the Internet for options, but in vain

worksheet.append_table() appends data to an existing table. Your code seems to append data on a new worksheet that does not have any tables. Try creating a table before appending data. For example, insert worksheet.update_row(1, ["Full name", "admin_id", "username", "Phone number", "Current time"]) before worksheet.append_table(new_row, start="A1", dimension="ROWS", overwrite=False).
